# Does OAuth authorization header allow me an access to the website itself (not API) as an authorized user?

Tags: asp.net, twitter, oauth, authorization

Let's say I use Twitter API to authorize my app. Using the headers that I get from the OAuth, can I access the website pages that aren't available as a guest directly, without using API?

If not, is there any other way to do it in ASP.NET C#?

Answer (score 0):

> Using the headers that I get from the OAuth, can I access the website pages that aren't available as a guest directly, without using API?

No.  The authorization token is for the API; not the website.

> If not, is there any other way to do it in ASP.NET C#?

You could theoretically write an application that behaves as a web browser, logs into Twitter, and then screen-scrapes the data you want.  This  would be much harder, less reliable and more time-consuming than using the API.